# Remotely accessing ubuntu terminal to connect to my digital ocean server

Tags: networking, ssh, webserver

I recently setup a digital ocean account for my development purposes. Just created a droplet and then connected to it using ssh though my home Ubuntu system.

Now, I want to be able to also access the same server (digital ocean droplet) remotely at my workplace. However my workplace system is running a windows os and it's a secure environment so I can't access the same way I do at home (using ssh). Even the basic websites like youtube are blocked.

The only way out I found is to somehow access the terminal (on the home server) through a web url on browser and then ssh into my DO droplet through there. To do that I can use something like tmate, gotty, webtty etc. But for that the Ubuntu terminal at my home needs to always on which is not possible.

I'm not sure how to solve this issue. Is there any way I can access that digital ocean server at my workplace using the web browser method? Are there any other options?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check with DO - I know linode.com offers a web-based console you can connect to via https and a browser.

Comment: Yeah that's available in DO. But it's considerably slow as compared to ssh